# Android loopj Async Http crashes after 1.4.5 update

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, httprequest, loopj

The new update for Android loopj Async Http lib is out and they changed a lot. Now you need to manually set `Looper.prepare()` otherwise it uses synchronious mode instead of async by default. I don't get where I need to set it.

Logcat

```
07-09 08:16:18.775: W/AsyncHttpResponseHandler(6606): Current thread has not called Looper.prepare(). Forcing synchronous mode.
```

After that message it totally crashes

```
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Synchronous ResponseHandler used in AsyncHttpClient. You should create your response handler in a looper thread or use SyncHttpClient instead.
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.sendRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:1096)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.post(AsyncHttpClient.java:873)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.post(AsyncHttpClient.java:856)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.post(AsyncHttpClient.java:843)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at com.xxx.app.HttpRequestGCM.post(HttpRequestGCM.java:15)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at com.xxx.app.ChatActivity$RegisterBackground.sendRegistrationIdToBackend(ChatActivity.java:681)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at com.xxx.app.ChatActivity$RegisterBackground.doInBackground(ChatActivity.java:660)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at com.xxx.app.ChatActivity$RegisterBackground.doInBackground(ChatActivity.java:1)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-09 08:16:18.835: E/AndroidRuntime(6606):     ... 5 more
```

My class for the Http Request:

```
import android.os.Looper;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.PersistentCookieStore;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

public class HttpRequest {
      public static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

      public static void setCookieStore(PersistentCookieStore cookieStore) {
            client.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
        }

      public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
          Looper.prepare();
          client.get(url, params, responseHandler);
      }

      public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
          Looper.prepare();
          client.post(url, params, responseHandler);
      }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 33):

I had a similar issue and found that making HTTP requests with an AsyncHttpClient in a thread caused the problem.

I ran my HTTP request outside of the thread and it fixed the problem for me. You can try something like:

```
public class HttpRequest {

  // A SyncHttpClient is an AsyncHttpClient
  public static AsyncHttpClient syncHttpClient= new SyncHttpClient();
  public static AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

  public static void setCookieStore(PersistentCookieStore cookieStore) {
      getClient().setCookieStore(cookieStore);
  }

  public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      getClient().get(url, params, responseHandler);
  }

  public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      getClient().post(url, params, responseHandler);
  }

  /**
   * @return an async client when calling from the main thread, otherwise a sync client.
   */
  private static AsyncHttpClient getClient()
  {
      // Return the synchronous HTTP client when the thread is not prepared
      if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
          return syncHttpClient;
      return asyncHttpClient;
  }
}
```

Comment: but how to properly prepare the looper and where to set i guess we want to use asynchronous mode

Comment: What if I dont want to use SyncHttpClient?

Comment: Ravi
You could either call Looper.prepare() or you could wrap your HTTP request call in "runOnUIThread" depending on where you want to make the call from.

@Lucas
If you don't want to use the SyncHttpClient, then you can make your HTTP requests outside of threads/AsyncTasks.

Answer (score 13):

I disagree with doing it Paul's way. Although I can't really see a good way to get around this as the way I'm about to present is fairly hacky as well, but instead of using AsyncHttpResponseHandler use this class instead

```
public abstract class AlwaysAsyncHttpResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I was trying to initiate a Async request from a thread (that would die soon). I have other synchronous calls in this thread, but for this call I wanted asynchronous and it was giving me an exception until I overridden the mentioned method. Thanks Tyler.

Answer (score 6):

I solve it with one code line

I separated my responseHandler

```
JsonHttpResponseHandler responseHandler = new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                RecorridoResponseDTO respuesta= new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), RecorridoResponseDTO.class);
                recorrido.setRecorridoId(respuesta.getA());
                mDataManager.actualizarRecorrido(recorrido);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
            }


        } ;
```

and this was the holy line

```
responseHandler.setUsePoolThread(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! That really was the holy line.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by passing parameter in AsyncHttpResponseHandler(Looper.getMainLooper()) like this.

First of all i used two classes one is MainActivity and Download Class. In MainActivity class, i call post method which is implement in the Downloadclass. Then Download class contains POST () which  was import from my library like import com.loopj.android.http.*;

MainActivity.Class

```
clientObj.post(context,url,entity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode,org.apache.http.Header[] headers,byte[] responseBody) {
        System.out.println(" Success ="+responseBody);
}
@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode,org.apache.http.Header[] headers,byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
    System.out.println( "Failure");
}
});
```

DownLoad.Class

```
    AsyncHttpClient asynClient = new AsyncHttpClient();


void post(Context context,String url, StringEntity entity,String string, AsyncHttpResponseHandler asyncHttpResponseHandler) {
    asynClient.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    asynClient.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    asynClient.post(context, url, entity, "application/json", asyncHttpResponseHandler );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because this version have a several bugs.

I high recomend you use OkHttp async layer, it's basically the same structure.

Or if you want the same structure based on OkHttpClient (Square Inc) use this:

https://github.com/leonardoxh/AsyncOkHttpClient

Comment: I just found the problem. It's because of the registration process of GCM. I just changed Async so Sync because this process is actually in an AsyncTask so it doesn't matter if it's Sync

Comment: Since 1 year after the comment ? I think you are mad.

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is not at all informative. "You have several bugs. You should switch frameworks." The first seems obvious, the second non sequitur.